# Correctly configuring SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

I have a bean to configure `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` but when I use `factory.setTaskExecutor(taskScheduler);` I get this log which delays the app start-up for more than 300+ seconds. But if I commented this **TaskExecutor** everything work fine.

**Log** on Debug level:

```
2017-04-24 15:48:45.449 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-4] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Initiating transaction commit
2017-04-24 15:48:45.449 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-7] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Initiating transaction commit
2017-04-24 15:48:45.449 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-1] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Initiating transaction commit
2017-04-24 15:48:45.449 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-2] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Initiating transaction commit
2017-04-24 15:48:45.449 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-6] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Initiating transaction commit
2017-04-24 15:48:45.449 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-3] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Initiating transaction commit
2017-04-24 15:48:45.449 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-8] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Initiating transaction commit
2017-04-24 15:48:45.449 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-5] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Initiating transaction commit
2017-04-24 15:48:45.450 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-4] o.s.a.r.connection.RabbitResourceHolder  : Skipping close of consumer channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,4), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.450 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-7] o.s.a.r.connection.RabbitResourceHolder  : Skipping close of consumer channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,7), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.450 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-4] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2017-04-24 15:48:45.450 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-2] o.s.a.r.connection.RabbitResourceHolder  : Skipping close of consumer channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,2), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.450 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-8] o.s.a.r.connection.RabbitResourceHolder  : Skipping close of consumer channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,9), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.450 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-7] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2017-04-24 15:48:45.450 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-4] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Created AMQP transaction on channel [Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,4), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.450 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-1] o.s.a.r.connection.RabbitResourceHolder  : Skipping close of consumer channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,8), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.450 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-2] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2017-04-24 15:48:45.450 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-6] o.s.a.r.connection.RabbitResourceHolder  : Skipping close of consumer channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,6), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.450 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-3] o.s.a.r.connection.RabbitResourceHolder  : Skipping close of consumer channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,3), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.450 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-5] o.s.a.r.connection.RabbitResourceHolder  : Skipping close of consumer channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,5), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-8] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-7] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Created AMQP transaction on channel [Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,7), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-4] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-WNpoLguXQUuqvsfU0XWgbg=accepted-queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,4), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-1] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-2] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Created AMQP transaction on channel [Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,2), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-6] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-3] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-5] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-8] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Created AMQP transaction on channel [Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,9), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-7] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-4-uSG6VKO__RhZW7e1Eqhg=queue-wait}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,7), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-1] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Created AMQP transaction on channel [Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,8), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-2] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-gNKSZWts2YmsHyIflgFBRw=exceptions-queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,2), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-6] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Created AMQP transaction on channel [Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,6), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-3] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Created AMQP transaction on channel [Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,3), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-7] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-4-uSG6VKO__RhZW7e1Eqhg=queue-wait}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,7), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-1] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Created AMQP transaction on channel [Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,8), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-2] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-gNKSZWts2YmsHyIflgFBRw=exceptions-queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,2), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-6] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Created AMQP transaction on channel [Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,6), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-3] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Created AMQP transaction on channel [Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,3), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-5] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Created AMQP transaction on channel [Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,5), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106]]
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-8] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-uAZX6E7qZilTn7YVzc9Gfw=cr-queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,9), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag--wz2ymgmywlECrSmcXvAhg=cr-queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,8), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-6] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-mWHmcoeXhWAd_z89yBQ22A=queue-wait}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,6), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-3] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-U2_lfDwU_B3WS_2epRAspw=exceptions-queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,3), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-04-24 15:48:45.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-5] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-0wfRlvj-gh96FFeDqNhCzQ=accepted-queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh,5), conn: Proxy@14aa069c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4f8c20a2 [delegate=amqp://localuser@localhost:5672/vh, localPort= 40106], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-04-24 15:48:46.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-4] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Initiating transaction commit
2017-04-24 15:48:46.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-7] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Initiating transaction commit
2017-04-24 15:48:46.451 DEBUG 28550 --- [     JWorkers-2] o.s.a.r.t.RabbitTransactionManager       : Initiating transaction commit
```

**My Configurations:**

```
@Autowired
private CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory;

/**
 * To configure @RabbitListener
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConcurrentTaskScheduler taskScheduler) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();

        factory.setTaskExecutor(taskScheduler); // When commenting this everything is fine
        factory.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(2);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(6);
        factory.setTransactionManager(rabbitTransactionManager());

    // use a non-transactional template for the DLQ
    RabbitTemplate dlqTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(this.cachingConnectionFactory);
    // When retries reach the maximum number that massage is dead-lettered to exceptions-exchange
    Interceptor retryInterceptor = RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateless()
            .maxAttempts(5)
            .recoverer(new RepublishMessageRecoverer(dlqTemplate, DLQueue.EXCEPTION_EXCHANGE))
            .build();

    factory.setAdviceChain(retryInterceptor);
    return factory;
}


public RabbitTransactionManager rabbitTransactionManager() {
    return new RabbitTransactionManager(cachingConnectionFactory);
}
```

This Spring Boot `1.4.1.RELEASE` running on Tomcat 8.0

Comment: These are all debug log which helps to identify the issues in rabbitmq if there is any failure or you want to know the more information about configuration....This is often used to prove to people that the listener thread is stuck in their code - if you don't see these logs then something is wrong.change the log settings to INFO or WARN or ERROR.

Comment: I'm running into an issue that I think is similar to yours. Were you able to get any more information?

Comment: @derickson82 check spring configuration and turn on the debug for spring, you may find the issue is not related to RabbitMq. GL

Answer (score 0):

> delays the app start-up for more than 300+

Since you only show 2 milliseconds of logs, and none of it relates to container start up, it's hard to say.

Using an external task executor shouldn't make any difference, as long as it can supply enough threads to satisfy the container's concurrency (in addition to whatever else is using the executor).

Edit your question to show the exact configuration (including the container and executor) that exhibits this behavior.